# getting Logger with year by year, month by month and day by day in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, logging, winston, chalk

I want to display the **log** file year by year, month by month and day by day in **Nodejs.** Please let me know how to display it in Nodejs. I have used **Winston Library** for creating log file.

want **separate folder** for year, month and day which is created at the time of log when user input the data. Whenever new month and new year is appear the folder is created automatically according to time.

Comment: you can then read the file system and show the year, month and day, on choosing the respective logs can be read and displayed. do you get any issue?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I am new to Nodejs. so, don't know the idea about it. sure will learn about file system and implement the same, If you know about this please eloborate something related to this --Thank You.

Comment: This should help you get started https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html